# Wordpress Gravity form custom Validation

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I created a form with gravity forms in Wordpress, But I'm trying to create a custom validation with an auto text field I create, So unless the user pick one of the option I put in the form, it should give an error.

I found this example on the gravity forms website, so this form give you an error if you enter a lower case "One and Two".

```
   add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_6_3', function ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): Running...' );
    // Only for Single Line Text and Paragraph fields.
    if ( $field->type == 'text' || $field->type == 'textarea' ) {
 
        if ( $result['is_valid'] ) {
            $stop_words = array( // List of words to not allow in lowercase.
                'one',
                'two',
            );
 
            if ( in_array( strtolower( $value ), $stop_words ) ) {
                GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): Stop word detected: ' . $value );
                $result['is_valid'] = false;
                $result['message']  = 'Sorry, you used a not allowed word.';
            }
        }
 
    }
 
    return $result;
}, 10, 4 );
```

I want to reverse it so that unless you put these specific words " one, two " you get an error

Answer (score 1):

You can add an exclamation point before the in_array() function which will make it stop any value not found in the array:

```
add_filter( 'gform_field_validation_6_3', function ( $result, $value, $form, $field ) {
    GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): Running...' );
    // Only for Single Line Text and Paragraph fields.
    if ( $field->type == 'text' || $field->type == 'textarea' ) {
 
        if ( $result['is_valid'] ) {
            $stop_words = array( // List of words to not allow in lowercase.
                'one',
                'two',
            );
 
            if ( !in_array( strtolower( $value ), $stop_words ) ) {
                GFCommon::log_debug( __METHOD__ . '(): Stop word detected: ' . $value );
                $result['is_valid'] = false;
                $result['message']  = 'Sorry, you used a not allowed word.';
            }
        }
 
    }
 
    return $result;
}, 10, 4 );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it works just fine on a normal text field, do you perhaps know how to use the same condition on a Autocomplete field in Gravity forms ?

Comment: Are you using a plugin for the Autocomplete?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Gravity forms advance Autocomplete field.